# useEffect getting firebase data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get my username from firebase.
console.log shows the correct username. But how can I access uName inside of useEffect to show it in my tet component?

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    var username = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("users/" + authUser + "/name")
      .once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot;
      });
    var slicedName = JSON.stringify(username);
    var uName = slicedName.slice(1, -1);
    console.log("USERNAMELOG", uName);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook doesn't allow `async/await` functions as the main handler. You can have it as a separate function and execute it within the hook:

```js
async function getData(authUser) {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users/' + authUser + '/name')
    .once('value')
}

useEffect(() => {
  getData(authUser)
    .then(username => {
      const slicedName = JSON.stringify(username)
      const uName = slicedName.slice(1, -1)
      console.log("USERNAMELOG", uName)
    })
}, [])
```

As for utilizing the `uName`, you can set it as component state or a global store if you have one (or context) to be accessible from other components.

EDIT:
If you're using `redux` then you should have a dispatch function to be able to update the global state with the `uName`. The only that that should change from the snippet above is that you replace `console.log` with some dispatch function you create and give the `uName` variable as an argument. Once it's in your Redux state, you should be able to propagate that value down to the components that need the value.

Comment: Could you explain utilizing uName a little bit more? This would be great! I use Redux